# Accessing Python module fails although its package is imported

Tags: python, import, package

My Django project's directory hierarchy looks like this:

```
+ pybsd
|---+ devices
    |---+ templates
    |---+ views
        |---+ interaction
            |---- __init__.py
            |---- geraete.py
            |---- geraetemodelle.py
            |---- geraetegruppen.py
        |---- __init__.py
        |---- ajax.py
        |---- html.py
        |---- misc.py
    |---- __init__.py
    |---- urls.py
|---- __init__.py
|---- urls.py
```

(Please excuse the German names. I preferred not to replace them here since it would add yet another possible error source when trying out the solutions you'll hopefully suggest and answering your questions.)

Every request to http://URL/devices/.* is dispatched to the urls.py file living in /devices:

```
# ...
from views import html, ajax, misc, interaction

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    # ...
    (r'^ajax/update/(?P<table>[a-z_]+)$', ajax.update),
    (r'^ajax/delete/(?P<table>[a-z_]+)$', ajax.delete),
    (r'^ajax/select_options/(?P<table>[a-z_]+)$', ajax.select_options),

    (r'^interaction/geraete/info/(?P<geraet>\d+)$', interaction.geraete.info),
    (r'^interaction/geraete/delete/(?P<geraet>\d+)?$', interaction.geraete.delete),
    (r'^interaction/geraetemodelle/delete/(?P<geraetemodell>\d+)?$', interaction.geraetemodelle.delete),
    (r'^interaction/geraetegruppen/delete/(?P<geraetegruppe>\d+)?$', interaction.geraetegruppen.delete),
    # ...
)
```

All URL definitions work except for those referencing the interaction package. I'm constantly getting the following error:

```
File "/home/simon/projekte/pybsd/../pybsd/devices/urls.py", line 33, in `<module>`
  (r'^interaction/geraete/info/(?P<geraet>\d+)$', interaction.geraete.info),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'geraete'
```

I double-checked that the `__init__.py` files don't contain anything.

*Maybe you've already found the (Python- or Django-related?) mistake I made and am apparently unable to see. If not, read on. In any case, thanks for reading this long post!*

---

### Isolating the problem

**1st test**

It works if I provide the view functions as strings:

```
(r'^interaction/geraete/info/(?P<geraet>\d+)$', 'devices.views.interaction.geraete.info'),
(r'^interaction/geraete/delete/(?P<geraet>\d+)?$', 'devices.views.interaction.geraete.delete'),
(r'^interaction/geraetemodelle/delete/(?P<geraetemodell>\d+)?$', 'devices.views.interaction.geraetemodelle.delete'),
(r'^interaction/geraetegruppen/delete/(?P<geraetegruppe>\d+)?$', 'devices.views.interaction.geraetegruppen.delete'),
```

... or add yet another line to the imports:

```
from views.interaction import geraete, geraetemodelle, geraetegruppen
```

Using `from views.interaction import *`, however, doesn't work either and results in the same error message.

---

**2nd test**

I created a file test.py in /devices:

```
from views import interaction
print dir(interaction)
```

Output:

```
simon@bsd-simon:~/projekte/pybsd/devices$ python test.py
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

Again, no sign of the modules I created in the interaction package (geraete.py, geraetemodelle.py, geraetegruppen.py).

Unlike in urls.py, trying `from view.interaction import geraete, geraetegruppen, geraetemodelle` in test.py results in `ImportError: No module named view.interaction` this time.

---

**3rd test**

I started the Django shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> import devices.views.interaction.geraete
>>> dir(devices.views.interaction.geraete)
['Abteilung', 'Auftrag', 'Auftragsvorlage', 'Geraet', 'Geraetegruppe', 'Geraetemodell', 'HttpResponse', 'HttpResponseBadRequest', 'HttpResponseRedirect', 'Raum', 'Standort', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'delete', 'info', 'models', 'move', 'render_to_response']
>>> 

$ python manage.py shell
>>> from devices.views.interaction import geraete
>>> dir(geraete)
['Abteilung', 'Auftrag', 'Auftragsvorlage', 'Geraet', 'Geraetegruppe', 'Geraetemodell', 'HttpResponse', 'HttpResponseBadRequest', 'HttpResponseRedirect', 'Raum', 'Standort', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'delete', 'info', 'models', 'move', 'render_to_response']
>>> 

$ python manage.py shell
>>> import devices.views.interaction
>>> devices.views.interaction.geraete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'geraete'
>>> dir(devices.views.interaction)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

Comment: Please change the title a bit. This is no really that much about Django than about Python itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When modules live in packages, and you import the package, Python does not automatically import all the modules in the package. Something in your program needs to import the modules you want to use. That can either be your `urls` module:

```
import views.interaction.gaerete
```

or, if you want `interaction.garaete` to always be available when you import `interaction`, it can be `interaction/__init__.py`:

```
import gaerete
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
import devices.views.interaction
```

and later

```
interaction.geraete
```

Python looks for *geraete* in the *`__init__.py`* module in the interaction package.

If you want to see this works, you may include `import geraete` explicitly in the `__init__.py` module.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly import the submodules if they are not imported in the `__init__.py` file:

```
import interaction.geraete
```